# How to center an image on page load

Tags: html, css, image

I have 2 images (both 3000px x 3000px) and I have one as background and one in front of it (frontal one will rotate).

Problem now is that I always start at top/left corner (0px x 0px)...I want to start at 1500px from left and 1500px from top (=center of the image), so without overflow:hidden, you can see the x/y scrollbars centered (vertical/horizontal).

Is there some way to achieve this effect?

```
html,
body {
    position: relative;
    background: url(stripes.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 3000px;
    height: 3000px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.stars{
    position: absolute;
    width: 3000px;
    height: 3000px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    z-index: 99;
    background: url(squares.jpg) no-repeat center;
}
```

these (bad) images will give you some understanding of the wanted effect

[image: this (bad) image will give you some understanding of the wanted effect]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you really need that large image? and if you actually give margin/padding of 1500 px from left, top it wont be shown at center on normal screen.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#image {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```